# Send email notification when a data in column matches a certain value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to make Google Sheets send a notification to a particular person/s when one of the fields on column Q is equal to the word "High". I want the email to be sent when it is high because it relates to the priority of the task.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should use a Google Sheets add-on or Google Apps Script. If you go for using Google Apps Script, you could use an on edit installable trigger,the MailApp or GmailApp services and one of the send methods of those services and JavaScript control statements to handle the rules.

Example (untested):

```
function sendNotification(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart === 17 and e.range.rowStart > 1){
    MailApp.send('manager@example.com','High Priority Task', 'Priority of task on row ' + e.range.rowStart + ' has set to high');
  }
}
```

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets